# Can’t talk to my teammates

Tags: overwatch, voice-chat

I picked Overwatch back up recently and have been grinding in competitive. But I’ve noticed that no matter what I try I can’t talk in team chat, I can hear my teammates but I can’t say anything.

My mic works fine, I can chat in Xbox parties, and I can chat perfectly fine in other games. Why can’t I talk to my team? I play on Xbox One.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem in OW on and off forever. Here's what I do which normally fixes it:

- In game, go into settings, and toggle Team Voice Chat off and on
- Unplug and replug the microphone
- repeat, with different combinations of having your mic plugged/unplugged with Team Voice chat toggled on/off.

It's really ridiculous that this problem has existed since the game came out and voice chat still doesn't work reliably.

Comment: I’ve tried all of this and none of them seem to work. I don’t think it’s as simple as turning it off and back on again.

Answer (score 0):

A missing or outdated audio driver may stop mic from picking up voice. Make sure that the audio driver on your PC is up to date. There are two ways to update your audio driver: manually and automatically.

Answer (score -2):

I've also had this problem before. So I contacted OV's help. They said you have to go to the settings, then audio settings, then press save, or it it still wont work buy a new pair of earbuds